# Swift - Http-Request with basic authentification

Tags: json, swift, http, authentication, request

i am working on a http-request with basic authentification to get the json from the web and parse it, this is what i got so far:

```
    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/api")

    let urlData = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseURL!)

    let json = JSON(data: urlData!)
```

As you can see, i am using the SwiftyJSON Library to get the json and parse it.

But my question is how to modify my HTTP-GET-REQUEST to include an username and a password if the webserver requires an basic-authentification.

Anybody dealed with this before and could help me with this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!!

Answer (score 0):

Initializing an NSData object directly with the data you're requesting is not the way to go in this case. You're going to want to take a look at how to use NSURLSession instead. With it you construct the request and are able to specify the method and parameters as well. It may look a bit more complex, but will also stop you from running into common problems. For example your code blocks when requesting the data, meaning that any UI on the screen will freeze up and not respond while the request is running.

Here's an in depth tutorial on NSURLSession to get you started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial